# Jupyter notebook: split screen vertically (i.e. add cell horizontally)

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to add a cell on the side of another cell, splitting the screen vertically?
This seems very useful when comparing two lists of things.

I don't see this options supported out of the box, so I am guessing it would require some extra js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This functionality has been [merged on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/10648) and will be in the 3.2 release. Go to `View -> Render side by side`

[image]

Comment: Is there a project for an "independant scroll" extension so that there is no empty spaces? When a cell is short but its output tall or the converse.

Answer (score 15):

This is now possible in [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html). See [this](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/seeking-suggestions-for-the-best-way-to-implement-a-split-view-jupyterlab-notebook-extension/2740/4) example:

> ...there is a menu item to create a new side-by-side view of that same notebook that will remain synchronized with the other view:
>
> [image]

Note that JupyterLab will eventually replace Jupyter Notebook. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56830184/11750716) answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can right-click a file tab, and select, "New View for Notebook."

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible at the moment (April 12th 2016), but there is a ticket in the Jupyter github issues that mentions that "soon" we will be able to open several notebooks in the same browser tab; That would allow for the side by side comparisons you are looking for.

Comment: I think the OP was referring to having multiple windows into the same file.  For instance, I am adding documentation cells at the top of my notebook, so I'd like to keep that cell open while I use the search feature to find things I'm documenting.   If I could open the same notebook under multiple tabs, that would probably do the trick.

Comment: @RufusVS can't you though? In the file browser mode, click the file you want to view, let it open up, then just click the same file again; then you'll have two browser tabs that you can move to separate side-by-side windows. I'm not sure they synchronize their content (I mean that if you make changes in one I don't think the changes show in the other), but that might be unnecessary for the OP.

Comment: @CrepeGoat : I misread the OP.  It looks like meto was trying to get a side-by-side view of two cells for comparison, which is different from what I was looking for.  (OP did say split "vertically" which I glossed over).    I was looking more for a "notebook split-screen editor",  which wouldn't work without synchronization between views.  Even a "collapse all cells" function might work for me. (only expanding the cells I was working with)

Comment: @RufusVS gotcha. Well from my uninformed perspective, I imagine a synchronous multi-window feature isn’t an outlandish request; go ahead and see if you can pitch it to the dev. team for future work, it’d be a nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Follow steps below.

1. Install extensions

```
>>> pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
>>> jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
>>> jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

2. Enable Splitcell extension
3. Open Jupyter notebook
4. Go to nbextensions tab

[image]

5. search for splitcell extension and enable it

[image]

6. Use it via the icon on any notebook thereafter.

[image]

And don't forget to check out other awesome extensions. Enjoy.