# JupyterLab vs JupyterNotebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, data-science, jupyter-lab

Hello everyone on Stack Overflow. Today, I would like to ask something very different question.

I am currently working as a data scientist, and I work alot on JupyterLab/Notebook. Couple of my co-workers use Notebook instead of JupyterLab. It seems like there are not much difference between those two (I really like how JupyterLab presents codes in different colors). I searched on the internet, and it says

"*JupyterLab is the next generation of the Jupyter Notebook*"

However, some featuers like plotly figures do not work well on JupyterLab but works well on Jupyter Notebook. I do not know why this is happening.

Can anyone who work on these two tell me the actual differences?

[image]

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982686/what-is-the-difference-between-jupyter-notebook-and-jupyterlab)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to work with Jupyter Notebook for about 4 years and last year I switched to Jupyter Lab. I think it is a nice improvement, I believe the biggest advantage is the improved user interface: it is much easier to switch between notebooks and everything feels more organized with tabs.

Concerning functionalities, the JupyterLab improvement is being modular: you can easily write your own plugins if you need it.

I have no experience using plotly, but I have similar issues with other packages. Everything was fixed in a short time, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was thinking too!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the notebook has a higher resolution and it is later versions. And the labs you are using former versions. Try upgrading that in Ana

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).