# What is different between Jupyterhub and simple Jupyter?

Tags: data-science, artificial-intelligence, devops

What is differents between Jupyterhub and simple Jupyter?

I want you describe in more detail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982686/what-is-the-difference-between-jupyter-notebook-and-jupyterlab)

Comment: @L0tad I didn't see JupyterHub mentioned on what you suggest? JupyterHub is covered in a section with that subheading at the bottom of [A Short Guide to Navigating the Jupyter Ecosystem: a no-nonsense overview of the Jupyter ecosystem, and a few tips, tricks and concepts you may find useful for navigating it](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/03/guide-navigating-jupyter-ecosystem.html). Basically JupyterHub allows multiple users to have their own Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab sessions served to them from a single machine. Example: [The Littlest JupyterHub](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Oops, I misread JupyterHub in the question as JupyterLab. My mistake.

Comment: no. you sent me link about jupyterlab and jupyter notebook. I want to know about jupyterhub and simple jupyter

Comment: Right, as I said, I misread your question. For starters though, have you read the documentation for [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html) and [JupyterHub](https://jupyter.org/hub) (specifically, the ["What is JupyterHub?"](https://jupyter.org/hub#what-is-jupyterhub) section)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "simple Jupyter", I assume you mean a local installation/environment in which you are running [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). [JupyterHub](https://jupyter.org/hub) is simply "a multi-user version of the notebook designed for companies, classrooms and research labs"—essentially just a piece of server-side infrastructure provided by the Jupyter project to help deploy a Jupyter environment for easy connection and use by multiple distributed clients.

Once connected, up and running, the interface and user experience is quite similar, except with JupyterHub it is running on a server somewhere that you usually connect to by pointing your browser to an external URL, instead of `localhost` or a specific address/port like you would use for a local Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: No it doesn't correct. I have run jupyter notebook remotely.

Comment: If you could expand upon what you mean by "simple Jupyter" then, that would help us answer your question.