# Jupyterlab split cell into 2 columns

Tags: jupyter-lab

I vaguely recall seeing split cells in jupyter notebook. I think this was done via changing the cell style to split. However, I can't find anything in jupyterlab that seems to do that. What I am trying to look for is the functionality to split one cell so that I can easily have a table and a chart next to each other. 
Is that possible?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? Still struggling here...

Comment: no, did not find anything yet

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a solution for Jupyter Notebook (haven't got a solution for Jupyterlab yet): please see "_Tip 1: Split slides into two columns_" [here](https://www.markroepke.me/posts/2019/06/05/tips-for-slideshows-in-jupyter.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter notebook: split screen vertically (i.e. add cell horizontally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462921/jupyter-notebook-split-screen-vertically-i-e-add-cell-horizontally)

Answer (score 2):

1. First install nbextensions:

   conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
   conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
2. Turn on 'split Cells Notebook in the configurator (see picture)

[nbextension configurator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs4oH.png)

3. Use the addon inside the notebook to split a cell:

[Inside the notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDhoR.png)

Comment: The works okay for jupyter notebooks. But it doesn't work jupyter-lab though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a work-around.

- Create another untitled notebook.
- separate original and new notebooks view in half.
- move the desired cells to other notebook.

(you don't have to execute cells , just copy and paste in other notebook).

Comment: Hi Swapnil. Thanks for your suggestion, but this is not a practical solution. I share workbooks with others, so having two workbooks is not very user friendly, having to scroll them in parallel a pain, ...