# Render cell output on the right side of code (side by side) in VS Code notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Similar to JupyterLab `View -> Render side by side` as in the question [Jupyter notebook: split screen vertically (i.e. add cell horizontally)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500576/9421451), is there a way to render the cell output of VS Code notebook `side-by-side`?

Comment: This function is not supported at present. You can make a request for this function in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues?q=side-by-side) and vote.

Comment: Might not be exactly what you are looking for, but PyCharm Professional Edition **up to version 2021.2.3** does output Jupyter notebooks side by side almost the same way (the difference is that the scrolling is independent with no blank space, which is better in my opinion).

Answer (score 4):

Its not an actual setting but a work around that I use which is by using `Split Right` on the Jupyter notebook tab I'm working on.

This way you can have one view looking at solely the output and the other view at the code you are editing.